# Replace ChromeOS with Ubuntu on Acer Chromebook 15 (cp315-1h-p8qy)

Tags: acer, 19.10, chromebook, chromeos

A colleague has asked for my help installing Ubuntu 19.10 onto her Acer Chromebook 15 (cp315-1h-p8qy).

I haven't found a tutorial for removing ChromeOS from this specific model, but other tutorials (for different models) say you must remove a write-protection screw from the motherboard before ChromeOS can be removed.

I've dismantled this laptop, but it isn't clear to me that any particular screw is dedicated to write protection. Please advise if you have knowledge of this motherboard (pictured below). Where is the write-protection screw?:
[image]

Ultimately, I'm trying to do a real Ubuntu installation, like I've done on Windows laptops numerous times in the past.

Comment: After having dealt with this laptop, I will never buy a chromebook of my own. Unlike Windows laptops, Chromebook's try too hard to prevent you from installing another OS, while with Windows laptops, the most trouble I've had is simply having to disable secure-boot in the BIOS. I avoid purchasing hardware with arbitrary intentional inflexibility.

Comment: According to https://mrchromebox.tech/#devices, you need to remove the CMOS Battery (https://wiki.mrchromebox.tech/Firmware_Write_Protect#Hardware_Write_Protection) for this device. Search for Acer Chromebook Spin 15 in https://mrchromebox.tech/#devices for more details.

Answer (score 2):

if you follow the galliumos installation guide https://wiki.galliumos.org/Installing/Preparing it talks about checking which models need the screw removed and this laptop doesnt have one.  It will still install linux but sometimes if you let the battery run out it will give you issues booting back into linux.  if this happens youll need to boot back into chrome, hit Ctrl-Alt-F4 i think and enter the chronos shell.  From there you enter sudo crossystem dev_boot_legacy=1 and you should be able to Ctrl-L back into linux from the boot screen  upon reboot.  Galliumos has options for various flavors of linux but be aware the onboard sound dosent work on the Apollo Lake processors, HDMI sound and bluetooth work.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think the cp315 has one.  you just have to use the crossystem dev_boot_legacy=1 option from the chrome shell if it gets borked on reboot

Comment: Would you care to make an [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1275202/edit) and explain **how** to apply your solution?